# Hyphen VS Apostrophe in temporal expressions

Tags: compound-nouns

I know that it is "**six years' experience**", and I know that it is "**six-minute video**".

my question is, can I replace the previous structures with "**six-year experience**" and " **six minutes' video**" .

Comment: I would say a 'six-year' experience refers to a *single* event, for example being marooned on an uninhabited island.

Comment: *Six year's experience* means you have done something for six years, gaining experience each year.  *Six-year experience* is an experience that lasts for six years.  So "I have six year's experience building houses."  And "Escaping from Moon Colony X was a six-year experience."

Answer (score 0):

The question here is really about using a noun as an adjective.

And, as such, **the possessive is a separate question**. That is because a possessive such as the **cat's pajamas** stands for the **pajamas of the cat** and is **unrelated to adjectives**. "minutes" is a noun, and, therefore, cannot be an adjective with the s.

- A six-minute video = six minute is used adjectivally.
- A six-year experience = same thing.
- A ten-year sting

Those are also sometimes written as: 10-year X or 6-minute Y, for example.

Six years' experience is a possessive. Or: Six years of experience.

I have six years' experience as an ABC. [possessive]
I have six years of experience as an ABC.

A six-year experience can be a long time. [adjective]

In short, adjectival use of nouns requires removal of the s.